# Getting errors creating MemSQL database

Tags: singlestore

I installed MemSQL per video instructions on the download page.  During installation it told me that port 3306 was unavailable to use with Master Aggregator, so changed it to 4000.  And I can connect to it via MySQL Workbench.

I attempt to create a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE EnterpriseCopy
```

It returns an error: `Error Code: 1748. You must add at least one leaf to the system to run CREATE DATABASE`.  Ok, so I go into Web UI and I see that none of the nodes (master aggregator on port 4000 or leaf on port 3307) are running.

[image]

I tried `ATTACH LEAF '10.82.60.43':3307`, but it came back with `Error Code: 1802. Leaf '10.82.60.43':3307 is currently 'offline' and cannot be attached back into the cluster until it is reachable and in the 'detached' state.`

So can I fix this and bring the master and leaf online and reachable?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, here's what worked for me:

1. Delete the nodes using: 
   `memsql-ops memsql-delete --all`
2. Re-deploy them : 
   `memsql-ops memsql-deploy -r master -P 3307
   memsql-ops memsql-deploy -r leaf -P 3308`

You can change the port number as you'd want.

Answer (score 1):

From the description provided it appears that your MemSQL Ops agents are running but the nodes themselves are not. You can start the nodes using:

```
memsql-ops memsql-start --all
```

Be sure to run this on the master aggregator host.

Comment: I ran the command and it responded with `Starting cluster` and it hung there for 15 minutes until I killed it with ^C.  Then it said `The cluster is still being started`.  Meanwhile, `show leaves` still shows everything offline.  What I am missing here?  Should I bring everything down, the restart?  If so, how?